# How to locate MySQL header files to compile qt

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

From the [qt documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsqlquery.html):

> **You need the MySQL header files and as well as the shared library
>   libmysqlclient.so**. Depending on your Linux distribution you may need
>   to install a package which is usually called "mysql-devel". [emphasis added]

How do I get these? I tried `apt-get install mysql-devel` but apt-get told me it was `Unable to locate package mysql-devel`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try using package: `libmysqlclient-dev`.

You can use `apt-cache search ...` to find packages.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm and I will accept your answer as soon as Stack Overflow will let me.

Comment: Nice update to your answer (apt-cache search). Given how many times I type apt-get, maybe I should start exploring its functionality a bit more. Thanks again.